# Why i get permission denied at docker ffmpeg execution

Tags: docker, ffmpeg

i want to make small gifs (miniclip) from a mp4 video using ffmpeg with php script in aws ecs.

The whole configuration is working with the symfony built-in server. Now i put the controller into local docker and now i get the following permission denied error:

```
ffmpeg version 5.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 11.2.1 
(Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219) 20220219 configuration: --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter -- 
enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libpulse -- 
enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 -- 
enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-lto --enable-postproc -- 
enable-pic --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-libxcb --enable-librist --enable- 
libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libvidstab --disable-stripping --disable-static -- 
disable-librtmp --enable-libaom --enable-libopus --enable-libsoxr --enable-libwebp -- 
enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-vulkan --enable-libdrm --disable-debug 
libavutil 57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100 
libavcodec 59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100 
libavformat 59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100 
libavdevice 59. 4.100 / 59. 4.100 
libavfilter 8. 24.100 / 8. 24.100 
libswscale 6. 4.100 / 6. 4.100 
libswresample 4. 3.100 / 4. 3.100 
libpostproc 56. 3.100 / 56. 3.100 
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, 
from 'https://vendery-streaming.fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/myvideo.mp4': Metadata: major_brand : isom minor_version : 512 
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41 
encoder : Lavf58.24.101 Duration: 00:18:10.37, start: 0.000000, 
bitrate: 3405 kb/s Stream #0:0[0x1](und): 
Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 540x960, 3331 kb/s, 30 
fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default) Metadata: handler_name : VideoHandler vendor_id : [0][0][0][0] 
Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, 
fltp, 69 kb/s (default) 
Metadata: handler_name : 
SoundHandler vendor_id : [0][0][0][0] /var/www/html/public/myimage.gif: Permission denied
```

What exactly tells me the error? The folder `/var/www/html/public/` exists but isnt writable?

The command from php i run the script is:

```
$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -ss 255 -t 4 -i '.$url.' -vf "fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -loop 0 /var/www/html/public/'.$outputFile.' 2>&1');
echo $output;
```

any idea is welcome.

1. the user is wrong. `shell_exec('whoami');` gives me www-data, but why?? My dockerfile have the following in: `RUN chown -R root:root /var/www/html/public`

docker-compose.yaml

```
symfony:
    mem_limit: 500M
    mem_reservation: 500M
    container_name: '${APP_NAME}-${APP_ENV}-backend'
    #environment:
        #- DATABASE_URL="mysql://${MYSQL_USER}:${MYSQL_PASS}@database/${MYSQL_DB}?serverVersion=mariadb-10.8.3"
    build:
        context: .
        target: symfony
    #restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
        - 8000:8000 #browser / container
```

Comment: If this is in the context of a Docker container, what's in the Dockerfile, and how are you starting the container?  What are the permissions on the target directory when you run the container?  (Is fixing the significant security problem in the `shell_exec()` call a good idea?)

Comment: in my dockerfile i have set user root, also in my php conf file which is been imported. I doesnt have a place where www-data is set. Starting the container with docker compose up --build. Its not my opinion to fix the security problems in shell_exec

Comment: The `docker-compose.yml` content is important: if you're mounting something else over `/var/www/html` then the contents of the Dockerfile are irrelevant.  (And the shell-injection vulnerability is serious.)

Comment: the docker-compose.yml is very normal, nothing special, i updated my question. Youre right with the shell.. but is there another method to do this what i want?